# Expression for $\|Ax\|_2^2$ in terms of rows of $A$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I am currently reading [1011.3027](https://arxiv.org/abs/1011.3027), Roman Vershynin's introduction to non-asymptotic random matrices. On page 24, there is an equation, (5.24), which reads

\begin{align*}
\|Ax\|_2^2 = \sum_{i=1}^n\langle A_i,x\rangle^2,
\end{align*}

where $A_i\in \mathbb{R}^n$ are the rows of the matrix $A\in \mathcal{M}_{r\times n}$ and $x\in \mathbb{R}^n$ is a vector (on the unit sphere).

I find myself believing this to be true, but I am not sure how to actually prove it. I tried playing around with an SVD and also decomposing $A$ as a sum of basic matrices but I didn't get anywhere useful.

Thus, I would appreciate a reference or proof of the above equation.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** What is the $i$-th element of the vector $Ax$, using the definition of matrix multiplication?

Comment: Row-one-times-column-one the mantra goes... $(Ax)_i=\langle A_i,x\rangle$. Got it. Thanks!